# trying to validate int input and reject decimal and spaces

Tags: c++

When user input is something like "3.2" or "3 2" the validation loops I'm using takes the first number as a valid int, then automatically passes the second number as as answer to the next prompt. I want it to reject anything besides integers entirely.

This is the relevant portion of my code-

```
int menu(std::vector <std::string> options) //menu creation
{
int input;             //user selection
bool check = false;    //check for valid input
.
.
.
while(!check)
{
    std::cin >> input;

    if(std::cin.fail() || input <= 0 || input > static_cast<int>(options.size()))
    {
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore();
        std::cout << wrongInput << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        check = true;       //change flag for valid input
    }
}
return input;
}
```

I use the static_cast to get the size of the menu into int form or else I get a compiling error saying it's not a proper comparison. I haven't seen other examples use this, so I don't know if that's what could be causing the improper acceptance of "3.2" and "3 2" as valid inputs.

Comment: Unrelated: `std::cin.ignore();` discards exactly one character. If the user types in a large string you'll repeat the error message many, many times.

Comment: Unrelated: Since you don't want negative numbers AND you have to cast the `vector`'s size  to make it signed, consider not using an `int`and use an unsigned type for input. eg `unsigned int input;` and then `if(std::cin.fail() || input > options.size())`. Also consider the downside of the `ignore` inside the body of the if. If the number was a valid number, so there is no input error to be cleared and no data to be ignored, but was out of range, that `ignore` will remove the first character of the next number typed in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::getline` to consume an entire line of input, and then perform validation on the input.

Since you are interested in a positive decimal number, you can check that the input consists of only decimal digits. One way to do that is to use the `first_not_of` method on the string to see if anything other than a decimal digit is found.

Your boundary checks on the values may still be necessary since the string may still specify a number not in range of an `int`.

```
std::string input;
while (std::getline(std::cin, input)) {
    if (input.find_first_not_of("0123456789") == input.npos) {
        unsigned x = std::stoi(input);
        if (x > 0 && x <= options.size()) {
            std::cout << "good input: " << x << '\n';
            continue;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "bad input: " << input << '\n';
}
```